# Gitolite on Windows - cloning stuck

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, gitolite

I have installed gitolite on windows server using cygwin, installation steps went without problems and when I try to "ssh gitadmin@gitserver info" from local machine(windows) I get the correct response:
`hello gitoliteAdmin, this is gitadmin@VRGWLSDEV1T running gitolite3 v3.6.1-6-gdc
8b590 on git 1.9.4.msysgit.0
 R W    gitolite-admin
 R W    testing`

If I try to clone using Git Bash I get error: 
`$ git clone gitadmin@gitserver:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
git: 'shell' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Did you mean this?
        help
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

If I try to clone using cygwin terminal on local mashine (using the same ssh key and I get the same valid gitolite message) it returns:
`$ git clone gitadmin@gitserver:gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...`

...and stays like that for enternity!

I have searched for multiple solutions, added PATH (with Git etc.) to .bashrc and .bash_profile files on gitolite designated server. Also added PATH to .gitolite.rc to include custom Git installation path (before that I did not recieve the gitolite message)

If you have any solution or idea what did I do wrong: please....HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by myself:

Mysis Git installation was confusing Cygwin. Added Git pack to Cygwin and removed Msys Git env. variables: everything woks perfectly now.